# My PDF text field after encryption become not visible in Chrome and Adobe Reader and visible in Mozilla and X-Change Editor

Tags: javascript, pdf, encryption, pdf-lib.js

I created a valid pdf with a single blank page and an existing text field, everything is fine:

[image]
I can edit the pdf and save it, everything is fine. I tested the pdf with tools for validation, the pdf is valid.
But when I encrypt it, with those permissions:

```
const securityOptions = {
   ownerPassword: "azer",
   permissions: {
     printing: 'highResolution', //'lowResolution',
     modifying: true,
     copying: true,
     annotating: true,
     fillingForms: true,
     contentAccessibility: true,
     documentAssembly: true
   }
 };
```

And save it, I have an issue with the text field when I open the pdf:
Text field invisible in:

- Adobe Reader.
- Chrome (and all chromium browser), when a do a ctrl+p the text field is visible in the print viewer.

Text field visible with its value in:

- Mozilla
- X-Change Editor

I tested the encrypted pdf with tools for validation (https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/validate.aspx), the pdf is valid.

This is the encrypted PDF, may be something wrong with the streams or Metadata encryption, I am not sure:

As base64

```
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
```

As text

```
%PDF-1.7
%

1 0 obj
<<
/CreationDate (D:20240103094920-05'00')
/Creator (PDF-XChange Editor 9.3.361)
/ModDate (D:20240105100343Z)
/Producer (pdf-lib (https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib))
>>
endobj

2 0 obj
<<
/AcroForm 4 0 R
/Metadata 5 0 R
/Pages 6 0 R
/Type /Catalog
>>
endobj

4 0 obj
<<
/DR <<
/Font <<
/Helv 7 0 R
>>
>>
/Fields [ 8 0 R ]
>>
endobj

5 0 obj
<<
/Length 3008
/Subtype /XML
/Type /Metadata
>>
stream
Kbù9Kw–5×ik¢w)-®•Æ‰yZˆ³­‚Æ´Î:$zûô7H+x·’À"~Ë¹Xí(t@¦‚eBÌ$îˆë´/øçS0¼~Å.#â™âu8²‡~ÚC)J¬vtä Ž
nôÎŽ¤‹yQlø°·c~£mÛµëè/Çhiì¹ÃgY#WWIZoþG-Þ÷qçz×ê ñ{N»ƒqB:§@Êì±{Õg§ºÅ½2+Fl*Í­ºu Yñ­Â    ÛÂsÎK‰qþÜ$+õÐ‡¼õF8w¼ïì™?'_\åµ0«è‡~X[ý2¶Sî5\Ð¥q££R¶G¯¤5 \=
BäV:ÁÒŽ>¢«ð¢šw»^,ÂÑÑ¿(UëÕöds‰ŽI‚>Ì,.— dÕÖ!ž”P¹¦ÿkÊ
S´M÷nñqkx¡
WoÄ8Í¨È·èQÂ=ýuÏÓyXûô¬#˜×g…¯O—Ž?#9&ãž«…ÍÇ÷ÞØ6)êS©
™¦:à7lYtãOuB˜êÎ§‡H×©6]þÍ¢cd2üßúÏ™™-ý,ÆˆÛçxN·â´ÔÅ¦l¯ h…‘ÕR®Ú6c Y§éYÉ j6bJxá‹^ùo¯d1š63©{‚6ê±uÈk-öã¯*žÆã2ªT7FcqÆÄhÄ¬;:]m]gŸåö–«q3™ø>É†ƒÛžB@X)?/N"…UJbcÜý²îÓéáRæ³JYè=FÖ;-“,óFeûº&§«Ÿ›ˆDÛ19Í VëÙ‚Ç›ß‹S_IäO‚xì¬ÆÍaËÇh‡yº{Wúe»'HÑX™ÅQà 7™ýàpû¬yM÷:æv‚¹_@`©†ú/;úî˜Fª}¢y`usxFÈª ø½ 2ä1þNÄ¶ø¦m…¡a
Ý×9nYî›° XÞ$òƒ“@¤ ðGK¯màqIà€éNŒÍíË4KÂ¤”8Ã<AŽCµòÕá·ÆFBÓY4d‰™@Z%ä§ßÙ 6@‡"rüúô;~‚çYX™^2ReÞ¹·}úž&3Ã—ebÆ pÿHÛp“‡°$ëˆ£Þ‚ì[!Pú»P   Ÿóu¦°‡³äL“8]´àØ†q¼IÛ
­i¶ê,gÆ;bh.Y
 p\ÕN9s¥­ôl7lMbŒÒ8oŒçµð´…!ƒÖ^~A|²½e½õ´†ûE(Ø¢ÌÀÀË-SK…¾Òú"xE§;¡A¤=:ßLa‘³,x6=iuçªÔAŸ ¶n.XýZ‚]°€”ìé*ÔŽh¹T’%ìÛ¹î&D2Ïýh1£n»)‹úæƒDî ìòördÂWŸ@yb5¤gn6)ªbaÕHÎJdÝ>N~ù÷þ2Ç€ð¿å?U‚‡‹x•²g::ç3¬-_%> äÐhÒiÌk·v]rC §äe£Ÿpy“s÷ÍÇV÷…üXEw|yÃßŸ=iÊú†¡)!eKë,x_uqrKrc8b‡X„)ÙÊ¢íL6A¬Bìê¼ä?%ÜÝÊ9±^HuuÞvI:•Ä‚6-FÃ#.{Ž|æ-¿6H4ŸOžëµý,Hl/5¹ƒ‡^é<³°PæJu
ºi³FPîØu›Ó"Iï>©ÇÂ‹‚ŒÎ*ET´)Kåv+ŒVm? ûÈ9á3·‰Æä¨x(…Ò¦ñDWºZG¡œDÕFÒëG€»­`AÉù¸ù[ò'S"Jß˜§Úƒv‘ÿvÜÄBßE:¸1.VE‰µÞ\EL´`
)&k2éà¤‹]E.Ï‘JÄÊ‚½Õ•R­7·0‚:s°˜ü«qéõlÏ¤Ã±#ËÛ{NÐ—Uì¢&ëWêÏÓú>˜¨Á”ö`4ZŒ.¦£­½ôgÅ6ÃL3³«ZëÜ÷{Zß‘J{7ŠË«M49E¸uuòo6m¸ylä±s.3=¾‚lÂ`½wÖ~šàÌœV*ÆåàCãÚ™~ÏzËPwöNEX&Gâ»œBGUl¯ÆËT<vüNýC_ÔÍï^.æâ,H ±b€äxö{6þØYÑá¦àõ‡G&””6É‡óXw7TWš^¼<\ÜÛÌhâ¥IL€icÌ¡RÎq^ÇpÕœì¼t­Ð÷¾S F“%Ü=ËOÎ²ù?¹kóŠYxßk)à
‚¢töZä6ú(cì¬Pb^ŠdÍGÅê¬²*ÌŠ£ÑBuÉ uApº?Ö*¤zf‚Æ+•2“Âó"ûdS;æ°ggÈÐí°{%ú¯GœÐ
±ÜÁ²õb'§ù7òÆœâN=N%¶¾ð>œºOÐï#oø}ÄƒŽrîø6£…LŒœpƒ[ñY³9¸{öçêÚ_3MÑDþ%¸CwäUìw`jÀŽÒaR+}aæ¯@àÙµYÒ†4}4
B¾åëáí„G !tß,Ú×ŸÏ‰á!ÍF|ê]˜µyç¡ÛæÊ_0RY>s¾|ò°-”J>"ÆC9Ÿì°Æß‘;ö¬^Óu·xª  Ç¦‰Þ–Êár]a\d5¬ëzþW@Û¼!+ìï´s6I
lÊI½3ˆM4ÌÞd\'.Ê÷þp¡«"¤"
ÙÁj¦šÉj´€E…¯=_y¡lvÕE·!Éê›^é´|Ts„ ãý­&ç Šù#–J3µMÁèÓÌLódK…¾ü,÷QD©`úÊ?ä²[™£ñã…Óc   ²ÅË]•JögÜjZäà$øäÖpü‘{÷ê xt‘˜‰¿Ù÷ÁŠP¦tú«tËW+Òö&«<ã|ë
ÀØî†z­é:‘¢5³ì—Â³¤·èy*ÊÎML‚Õƒ&@ ®ñ5Ü6ç ôGlhC,°ýQ(H·ò16žz¶Ó_Ëê X)‰áæ£±i=‰M
eH˜5L
iGÏ. ž?zÐ ¼ä¾…cšô÷µÄù…ÀoOÎûô¯® Ù[ÇA
(MÆÈáö":çhË;°d¨ˆ3Hd}AÐ/££žaX\xZÇ¿áóú²Å­5Ãl rŠ`æ?‰hº;Çä3QÐ«1Œ/wNU¥™Àé’.K¸¥y
‘ób ŸÕùÅ<“ §èW4 0cIõAšÇoåJö5öƒø„±†YïŒ'¬<DÑ~äçmÕSî³"éžId°+©Âü8®ü„¾´î0£°\Qw’Es§:?x!ûf†E0Óž¯¢^—(R=1ï¿^û#:
2kiBxô´ÖŠÜ]Ë¬²9p<­É*¿iŒ)ï=ÜÈÃ¤ùÀSã@“›@jŒu5÷i˜ñÇÂsÖ R<’±‡÷Õ…àØ£š%Ý#½¢Aq4?kxL!¨/Ãñ<eÄÚ¢šÜàÄ„D6!¤¢SúžH&¤êoÔ[,-Gj¿Œ]T—+že3s+‰ù
Õa8!0,¹G;Ýôø±§ší,Ù×$DÕöMõÎ$å3Z…g =?^áúò×Ñ   `¯WjÞw[²[—ÁÌê‡m‰[ÆÆiŸ
W"2åö3>Úö´vAžx
¿¡KÊÏDç¯´­j—ß‡«Î/LŸ­/ÝmwÎÙf*o±Éìf"^BØ®#úe =DÅR»Œ7éÜeë0Eb‰ŠAcí±»ømV–l(Ðó¯båaòyÐ"sUÂ$O5Î}.³ð©ŠÄ†6'Â±]ß ¿pRZG^ÍPâ‡&äÝ‡âixDÈ›ÁW”}ÃìÑÂ´…¦;Éaèfª>ÃR¨öMÃ¿æ é¼=îþO_åØôèXÖ0ò/þd ÓM¸ÊÒ­ZÓ§tòS$dAó´L¤-Cû²:Í3^f$UÂl£ób<5óZ|X«YƒvË{HÎ    ¹(‘½Ÿ:q2˜VÝkÈ9ýsw¨  ÒdH8žÐÕç¦ñxÞffSK#’;¨«ÄõÐôÆ
endstream
endobj

6 0 obj
<<
/Count 1
/Kids [ 9 0 R ]
/Type /Pages
>>
endobj

7 0 obj
<<
/BaseFont /Helvetica
/Encoding 10 0 R
/Subtype /Type1
/Type /Font
>>
endobj

8 0 obj
<<
/AP <<
/N 11 0 R
>>
/DA (0 g /Helv 0 Tf)
/DV (I am a default value)
/F 4
/FT /Tx
/MK <<
/BC [ 0 0 0 ]
>>
/P 9 0 R
/Rect [ 32.076511 725.777222 182.076508 747.777222 ]
/Subtype /Widget
/T (Text1)
/Type /Annot
/V (Hello SE)
>>
endobj

9 0 obj
<<
/Annots [ 8 0 R ]
/MediaBox [ 0 0 612 792 ]
/Parent 6 0 R
/Resources <<
>>
/Type /Page
>>
endobj

10 0 obj
<<
/Differences [ 24 /breve /caron /circumflex /dotaccent /hungarumlaut /ogonek /ring /tilde 39 /quotesingle 96 /grave 128 /bullet /dagger /daggerdbl /ellipsis /emdash /endash /florin /fraction /guilsinglleft /guilsinglright /minus /perthousand /quotedblbase /quotedblleft /quotedblright /quoteleft /quoteright /quotesinglbase /trademark /fi /fl /Lslash /OE /Scaron /Ydieresis /Zcaron /dotlessi /lslash /oe /scaron /zcaron 160 /Euro 164 /currency 166 /brokenbar 168 /dieresis /copyright /ordfeminine 172 /logicalnot /.notdef /registered /macron /degree /plusminus /twosuperior /threesuperior /acute /mu 183 /periodcentered /cedilla /onesuperior /ordmasculine 188 /onequarter /onehalf /threequarters 192 /Agrave /Aacute /Acircumflex /Atilde /Adieresis /Aring /AE /Ccedilla /Egrave /Eacute /Ecircumflex /Edieresis /Igrave /Iacute /Icircumflex /Idieresis /Eth /Ntilde /Ograve /Oacute /Ocircumflex /Otilde /Odieresis /multiply /Oslash /Ugrave /Uacute /Ucircumflex /Udieresis /Yacute /Thorn /germandbls /agrave /aacute /acircumflex /atilde /adieresis /aring /ae /ccedilla /egrave /eacute /ecircumflex /edieresis /igrave /iacute /icircumflex /idieresis /eth /ntilde /ograve /oacute /ocircumflex /otilde /odieresis /divide /oslash /ugrave /uacute /ucircumflex /udieresis /yacute /thorn /ydieresis ]
/Type /Encoding
>>
endobj

11 0 obj
<<
/BBox [ 0 0 150 22 ]
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 144
/Resources <<
/Font <<
/Helv 7 0 R
>>
>>
/Subtype /Form
/Type /XObject
>>
stream
q'I,][‚ŒÌÀtÙ·rR‹ÇåbVÀŠ  b^ÄQWÖÑÞvûSÌ=rÕ–ïç^ÐðsùV…ž¸ "E+—BªÑ#t©  [4cä¡pûðGÔŽ‹¨€£c5ÿØEx„RBïwUxªðäF>”'<¥œñkþžUU“Š4)
3ÐJÉO%Múÿ°Ü
endstream
endobj

12 0 obj
<<
/ModDate (D:20240105100345Z)
/Producer (pdf-lib (https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib))
/Creator (pdf-lib (https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib))
/CreationDate (D:20240105100345Z)
>>
endobj

13 0 obj
<<
/Type /Font
/Subtype /Type1
/BaseFont /Helvetica
/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
>>
endobj

14 0 obj
<<
/Type /Font
/Subtype /Type1
/BaseFont /Helvetica-Bold
/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
>>
endobj

15 0 obj
<<
/ModDate (D:20240105100345Z)
>>
endobj

16 0 obj
<<
/Filter /Standard
/V 4
/Length 128
/CF <<
/StdCF <<
/AuthEvent /DocOpen
/CFM /AESV2
/Length 16
>>
>>
/StmF /StdCF
/StrF /StdCF
/R 4
/O <8a93ac1e4c390a3351364adb88835ac7c283cf5a348242ece01d07acf8ba4ec6>
/U <075a3fa40c89c5f57fba188347dd8a8f00000000000000000000000000000000>
/P -4
>>
endobj

xref
0 3
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000016 00000 n 
0000000202 00000 n 
4 13
0000000284 00000 n 
0000000358 00000 n 
0000003449 00000 n 
0000003509 00000 n 
0000003597 00000 n 
0000003841 00000 n 
0000003950 00000 n 
0000005278 00000 n 
0000005588 00000 n 
0000005787 00000 n 
0000005886 00000 n 
0000005990 00000 n 
0000006042 00000 n 

trailer
<<
/Size 17
/Root 2 0 R
/Encrypt 16 0 R
/Info 15 0 R
/ID [ <0e64bebcd34321987c69258cf231ea8c> <0e64bebcd34321987c69258cf231ea8c> ]
>>

startxref
6343
%%EOF
```

The not encrypted PDF:

```
%PDF-1.7
%

1 0 obj
<<
/CreationDate (D:20240103094920-05'00')
/Creator (PDF-XChange Editor 9.3.361)
/ModDate (D:20240105100317Z)
/Producer (pdf-lib (https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib))
>>
endobj

2 0 obj
<<
/AcroForm 4 0 R
/Metadata 5 0 R
/Pages 6 0 R
/Type /Catalog
>>
endobj

4 0 obj
<<
/DR <<
/Font <<
/Helv 7 0 R
>>
>>
/Fields [ 8 0 R ]
>>
endobj

5 0 obj
<<
/Length 2979
/Subtype /XML
/Type /Metadata
>>
stream
<?xpacket begin="ï»¿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="XMP Core 6.0.0">
    <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
        <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
                xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
                xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/"
                xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/"
                xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/">
            <dc:format>application/pdf</dc:format>
            <xmpMM:DocumentID>uuid:f0bc7a01-dd93-4c4e-9bec-783a9464b1c0</xmpMM:DocumentID>
            <xmpMM:InstanceID>uuid:6b75ef77-09b1-43ed-8d0b-d5721e91bdea</xmpMM:InstanceID>
            <xmp:CreateDate>2024-01-03T09:49:20-05:00</xmp:CreateDate>
            <xmp:CreatorTool>PDF-XChange Editor 9.3.361</xmp:CreatorTool>
            <xmp:ModifyDate>2024-01-05T04:52:55-05:00</xmp:ModifyDate>
            <pdf:Producer>PDF-XChange Core API SDK (9.3.361)</pdf:Producer>
        </rdf:Description>
    </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                           
<?xpacket end="w"?>
endstream
endobj

6 0 obj
<<
/Count 1
/Kids [ 9 0 R ]
/Type /Pages
>>
endobj

7 0 obj
<<
/BaseFont /Helvetica
/Encoding 10 0 R
/Subtype /Type1
/Type /Font
>>
endobj

8 0 obj
<<
/AP <<
/N 11 0 R
>>
/DA (0 g /Helv 0 Tf)
/DV (I am a default value)
/F 4
/FT /Tx
/MK <<
/BC [ 0 0 0 ]
>>
/P 9 0 R
/Rect [ 32.076511 725.777222 182.076508 747.777222 ]
/Subtype /Widget
/T (Text1)
/Type /Annot
/V (Hello SE)
>>
endobj

9 0 obj
<<
/Annots [ 8 0 R ]
/MediaBox [ 0 0 612 792 ]
/Parent 6 0 R
/Resources <<
>>
/Type /Page
>>
endobj

10 0 obj
<<
/Differences [ 24 /breve /caron /circumflex /dotaccent /hungarumlaut /ogonek /ring /tilde 39 /quotesingle 96 /grave 128 /bullet /dagger /daggerdbl /ellipsis /emdash /endash /florin /fraction /guilsinglleft /guilsinglright /minus /perthousand /quotedblbase /quotedblleft /quotedblright /quoteleft /quoteright /quotesinglbase /trademark /fi /fl /Lslash /OE /Scaron /Ydieresis /Zcaron /dotlessi /lslash /oe /scaron /zcaron 160 /Euro 164 /currency 166 /brokenbar 168 /dieresis /copyright /ordfeminine 172 /logicalnot /.notdef /registered /macron /degree /plusminus /twosuperior /threesuperior /acute /mu 183 /periodcentered /cedilla /onesuperior /ordmasculine 188 /onequarter /onehalf /threequarters 192 /Agrave /Aacute /Acircumflex /Atilde /Adieresis /Aring /AE /Ccedilla /Egrave /Eacute /Ecircumflex /Edieresis /Igrave /Iacute /Icircumflex /Idieresis /Eth /Ntilde /Ograve /Oacute /Ocircumflex /Otilde /Odieresis /multiply /Oslash /Ugrave /Uacute /Ucircumflex /Udieresis /Yacute /Thorn /germandbls /agrave /aacute /acircumflex /atilde /adieresis /aring /ae /ccedilla /egrave /eacute /ecircumflex /edieresis /igrave /iacute /icircumflex /idieresis /eth /ntilde /ograve /oacute /ocircumflex /otilde /odieresis /divide /oslash /ugrave /uacute /ucircumflex /udieresis /yacute /thorn /ydieresis ]
/Type /Encoding
>>
endobj

11 0 obj
<<
/BBox [ 0 0 150 22 ]
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 122
/Resources <<
/Font <<
/Helv 7 0 R
>>
>>
/Subtype /Form
/Type /XObject
>>
stream
xÚÉ1
Â@@Ñ~NñKm63!qM›°˜&…fÀh$(¦0âée›Ïƒ¯(Êé€±J¨    5V5”Æ21Já_Ú¡“·†U{JÍçÌSZåŽâ—œSÅÙKÑOó‹¡Áo”T!6q‡_eÓOóübL[Hr9J:ùÇ"š
endstream
endobj

12 0 obj
<<
/ModDate (D:20240105100317Z)
>>
endobj

13 0 obj
<<
/Type /Font
/Subtype /Type1
/BaseFont /Helvetica
/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
>>
endobj

14 0 obj
<<
/Type /Font
/Subtype /Type1
/BaseFont /Helvetica-Bold
/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
>>
endobj

xref
0 3
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000016 00000 n 
0000000202 00000 n 
4 11
0000000284 00000 n 
0000000358 00000 n 
0000003420 00000 n 
0000003480 00000 n 
0000003568 00000 n 
0000003812 00000 n 
0000003921 00000 n 
0000005249 00000 n 
0000005537 00000 n 
0000005589 00000 n 
0000005688 00000 n 

trailer
<<
/Size 15
/Root 2 0 R
/Info 12 0 R
/ID [ <482C1B0356F27EAD2EB01BDF7B8A9DF9> <482C1B0356F27EAD2EB01BDF7B8A9DF9> ]
>>

startxref
5792
%%EOF
```

I had encrypted/decrypted the /AP but it doesn't work this is the unzipped /AP:

```
0 0 0 RG 1 w
.5 .5 149 21 re S
/Tx BMC
q
1 1 148 20 re W n
BT
0 g 0 Tc 0 Tw 100 Tz 0 Tr/Helv 17.9 Tf 2 4.7976 Td
(Hello SE)Tj
ET
Q
EMC
```

As bytes Array:

```
[120,218,21,201,49,10,194,64,16,64,209,126,78,241,75,109,54,51,33,113,77,155,176,152,38,133,102,192,3,104,20,36,40,166,48,226,233,101,155,207,131,175,40,202,233,128,177,74,168,9,53,86,53,148,198,50,49,74,225,95,218,161,147,183,24,134,85,123,74,205,231,204,83,90,23,229,142,226,151,156,21,83,197,127,217,75,209,79,243,7,139,161,193,111,148,84,33,54,113,135,95,101,211,79,243,252,98,76,91,127,72,114,57,74,26,58,249,3,199,34,30,154]
```

Maybe i did a badly edited the /AP,, maybe the size and the xref, i changed them, I don't know what is missing in my encryption

Comment: Please share the pdf files as binaries and not as text.

Comment: One thing is immediately visible, though: the cross reference tables of both your unencrypted and your encrypted files are broken, the initial table must consist of only one subsection while yours are both split.

Comment: I shared as text to be visible but I just edited the post and added the base64 of the encrypted pdf, for the unencrypted one i can't because of the characters limitation, so when you mention the cross reference tables you mean the xref ? by the way I use pdf-lib, is this library causes problem in the the cross reference tables ?

Comment: *"when you mention the cross reference tables you mean the xref ?"* - yes. *"by the way I use pdf-lib, is this library causes problem in the the cross reference tables ?"* - I only can say that they strictly said are broken (albeit in a way many pdf processors ignore). You say pdf-lib created them, so apparently pdf-lib has a bug there.

Comment: @KJ In fact we only need to lock the pdf that the reason why we have the password on it. In fact in our solution if you remove the password like you did, the integrity of the pdf will be change and the pdf will not be rejected by our system. We need to lock it for business flow need.

Comment: Thank you @mkl for your responses, they are enlightening. I've seen your profile and you seem to have a lot of experience with PDFs. I have 2 questions for you. 1- Can you suggest a tool to debug the structure of the PDF and identify the initial problem? 2- Do you think that the reference table could be the source of my issue?

Comment: *"Do you think that the reference table could be the source of my issue?"* - maybe not of the field visibility problems. But if your files eventually are used in signing related work flows with multiple signatures or signature extension, you'll run into problems.

Comment: *"Can you suggest a tool to debug the structure of the PDF and identify the initial problem? "* - unfortunately such errors often are best identified by strict comparison with the spec, not by ready-made tools.

Comment: *"I just edited the post and added the base64 of the encrypted pdf"* - I'll analyze that next week when I'm back at my laptop.

Comment: As far as I can see in the posting the "encrypted" file only is partially encrypted. In particular the value of the field is not encrypted. Thus, any plausibility check of a viewer will discard the appearance.

Answer (score 2):

As already indicated in a comment, the PDF *claims* to be fully encrypted, i.e. both strings and streams, but the strings actually are *not* encrypted while the streams (Metadata and widget appearance) indeed are. Consequentially, strings like the name of the field and its current value cannot be decrypted.

Essentially, therefore, the PDF is broken.

How different PDF processors handle this, is implementation dependent. Some viewers ignore that the underlying form structure of the PDF is broken and display the widget annotation nonetheless, some try and repair the form structure internally while displaying either the original widgets or creating new ones from the repaired values, and some simply refrain from displaying the widgets of a broken form structure altogether.

> I tested the encrypted pdf with tools for validation (https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/validate.aspx), the pdf is valid.

If that tool indeed tests your PDF as valid, then I get doubts concerning the quality of that tool.

Answer (score 0):

If i want to encrypt with pdf-lib, this library recommend us to use a Save() with object stream as False:

```
pdfBytes = await pdfEncryptDoc.save({ useObjectStreams: false });
```

And in a ligne of code i see that the encryption is called just for stream instance:

```
if (!(idx < len)) return [3 /*break*/, 4];
indirectObject = indirectObjects[idx];
[ref, obj] = indirectObject;
xref.addEntry(ref, size);
// Only encrypt item that is under PDFStream
// Run the content through EncryptFn and update the content
// before compute of object size to ensure correct buffer size
if (pdfSecurity && obj instanceof PDFStream) {
  this.encrypt(ref, obj, pdfSecurity);
}
size += this.computeIndirectObjectSize(indirectObject);
if (!this.shouldWaitForTick(1)) return [3 /*break*/, 3];
return [4 /*yield*/, waitForTick()];
```

I think by using stream as false in the save method the objects don't become streams so they haven't been encrypted, but if i use the stream in the save method the pdf become no valid.

May be i have to use object stream and try to figure out where the use of object stream causes problem, here the result when i use object stream:

As base 64:

```
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
```

As Text:

```
%PDF-1.7
%

5 0 obj
<<
/Length 3008
/Subtype /XML
/Type /Metadata
>>
stream
SÙ)ó0‰¤gÑw’*·Â_€ÍbÔe  VôÔ˜!R÷Nï9Â?o;÷cçÜ½   ˜MÅ_À×Äß ´Áëˆ¢BßÌ"XkHãïç°ÌØ]üô1Ë·º«Tî@Ù­„Bá)Âd­#a¡þæÑyôEØNk—ƒËaoÀÈ¬G]{VÆr—À"´¡ºöñVão&"j]]Q†Û­Uòàµ;Ï<Y¢Ë×cªÔqªqô×!mS—äð¨Dçcžô¨³â®‡öU=î·¶×…‡Á
åcIƒ´Ð»4Â·ú˜ÎÂKˆ5i¢—“^žÖò6V<ÙuƒÙ0Üìh'ì¡ïÏ»¡MÛÎ%øæøA†ßò†kV1ööÞ1¸´˜±*&­¥~“#ýu¾û-_g×º¼œ­ÀÁ0‘pÖËÀ—ø`yy‹…ôû$“¨×‚sÛŠDÙåQ¨Ðh¥äÌÎ>Æf›Yli‰™]ó‡¹\£úE¨è®
j×»SŸùƒ
öI&…E9¯?Þˆ7|×ÊûtÓð¥Ë×Qž[“Ûh3t'œËXRëm¨â•šÓ6Ù€M:BýŽWºZlÛ@Ü›•ÒK•1êå5>ñýÖ™Ožô7ãçí5®×*LÄ>œ‹ïŠ ÃTÜŠÙ VøaJ¾ûÒän¸ý³‹š’ý2‘r|jÎÑg[uŒ¾òBGÛ’Î´œ•ãwÕ"Ù
éˆg¶‹`ùêÑB‰Ÿ´ŒbüG]y•YÎ¿c°0\M˜Árq;Ó—…'¸-P‚Ñ‹‘À™­êÓ©Ýª]n˜×Sxªõl
>‰rÅ¬;šÃÂù~ÞK1;l ¦b´|ø†‹ÙYy¶“ÁRßB3IlÓûn„ãïŒyÿƒä•mSÕÙÁ+¡-{Û#C.1}ûîBôí sµŒ©’œÎ:|tDa
    ³Ã
:þâº5Q£{ Œ<~ÖÓÜKïáŸ+«U&Awk÷Ò2‚6k®^}¤/àÕ#ZH÷NÉx@æOÁ[n÷ÁÜPN+zå›ãÝç£ÀÓOl*}ZìF¯Ù?"9T#KÂ‘
'®ïºÏÝÆ±¿vØäÁ:ºä´š‹®Éƒ³CÄ{óÉ‹peo¡ûubs&³M*à«'¡»Â=ß÷˜Î ¨lJÊ²À¯5—
µ!µ#®Ù
Æ%(ôc½eW'­y/UÙ­Ô
² I°W×à¬ã¹*fŽÓß”e¹ÿC7­Áš¡Ù“ƒS²åöœ†ñhÐõcº6ml¨ÈåeQL6åP<lÅ<Ú5¼k*.U%[–í$05Ô…„{·5ñÃßjç½¡|Gm–k©ßSéw NåÅÍ;h|¦¨
Qß§[H%^I!0NâRbÊƒ­F™€«‹’–°­¶×Ñ°†kÕ
iŽaí4Öº§   ÑQ®±ëP‰È%Â[rt­G7àè øÏ!›˜šnëÕ—};%•)ÔÒÝÂ¡+Ð±y[¹³ç‘X¤³—ÑBæ2¶­ãïÂÂ½D5Ç£~Ä—²j‹âÿ½‘öPÑ)q:F?ØÏšlâé×PWÐ2›\Êë\~"}!7|Aª½ã†F¡¦]°R&T@äf˜v«ˆU‰í«ú”%.ä†ñoŠ¸&hþGsíŠ7`÷ Ú×Ò&F‰Ú&x†êÂ&–€<Àv´1v3Â,ØY¨±>“¯÷`u[’BÁ_JÚå[ë¹ŽŒ´£±ä
dÚ¨ã«N2D».<jw÷™¬–­·<¤}íA=ÉmFpÝÚhPïÅÔ ~˜ºÇI_RƒóÆÐHwŽJV7zwØÐò³­òšÍC@Y®ÚÃœ©>
/kx…éJù„Î¼Ô[Äm™y€÷–éO8•­ŸºÑ5YÇ-Æ?³R¢†8ZÈ ˆ}’)@_¾ž.D{Œåàmè¸!oœO]¹œi
yûÓÖ\Kä¸‰åOž_õq3ØŠT´Ú7ÚŸ´8¥½$1ôéð£eÅ(<¤»a@|~!gÝ9^»sÙˆlª$;Â(µÌ;
—Õ2½>ÈsI<t–Å   =‘*úUÃd…Æ>µŒô.|ç‡ÓÍbaðê*ÒñúxÜ=[†›êPA.ðÉÓ×<¯V-_µwçfFWL ¸Zí-­§OF¢ô~F‰ïƒ€ŠŠW‹ºd)‰n(ºîxÿƒœ}žµ7‹@”¿ý\\™³û…Hc€T[á1ißl»Ä dTd‘[‰‘Ù¤fS_nŠu*RKa
4‚¸†7ŒïRãŠ¸Œö™:¢mO9aP?
B -@"
²ÂlYIšŠð;gŒ(æù)&N”¬:÷»WS­y“8B×vQŒ„¦Øêœ‰Ñ•òï°õ…&ÉÇ^5:H@Lq.{å‚g¸MSˆ2¥èeÌ·«õtY$Âœ9®+ƒ– X©“'¹;‹ÓXìAÂ\1`[Îã]ðïýÊ¤ÄšXÑÏ-Ô™ë]"…—_½€§Šý:ðSúßi¾-çAyåæœÅÑ0¡ÿÈ&Ö>èØR`SKŽ½yK+  ÈÂRQÈ^Ž¤ÛšQÚSfF(ý b¿\´O<È£ŠÈøê?ªËK¶!æC¤ùéÛðw-™È]    n×5^Š¤—Y]Q¦jÍÅ@Rii—Ã¹[{5@à¦e¶½˜aHõÝ¯s aNª= ”Gw„ýâÅ»H ÚÈöìg¹0û*B¯ZK¹Úò`!›o’wPï·M¦Cý^§zßu®…µˆ ¡‡ÑÛ¨È;#§P·Iåž± b–f‡[A‚P²Ë£ž‡gûöwŸ°e·ùG¯m’p‘«d% ¢p¹E|qEdÒ!ŽÔ‰¼š—
Ûqî²¾µ€ÍrÃ_­¥R6üâ|xë^ö "¼·Î$’ù©u”Å!Ê¦™ÓÞ™¸å–N‰ÛŽ“ò?”Ä»HgÊ³û£ÐîÑ~Dr :;¦'nV3™ÐÇðÐmž·hÆÚË\€G(ÝW   ®o[™cÊæå•MEDÒb5b$Xê•Éî·Âv=‰ÙZ
üæÏ¢k3ª~9$=žµUãÕ‡›|Ž=k†gº<ö~Åp_ÝC!µê>0'
ü0r•='[ 1¢?ñxZ‚/m­ÁXzeþVýrVoIÞ_]¹—¼‚š›ÏeLnŽ€“~A>Ï!t¦à/gékÿÄI…eŠdìbzÍTm–Ÿ[|ÛMJ%
<IÀX­òáí½O~œ®£ÁIÖ èxmü¸Ò#eÖ[Fo™õ
’½‹lYÓd/ƒúpwS{¢.×)åòe’¡Ê’Àè˜7¯qKìí!B¨4€¸‰íí”Š¾hE‘–]ì¹
ôÆÉuøïë…¡£èÎÁ»?2b(Ë=ÃX®ï˜ØgûXw·õ6’ÅS{¸}Ó¶.FgŽˆï6·N    ‹£q    ‘$Ï6”Ð';þ™âüÓÿË5À–éþˆÕÎë&€yÌKÑh¦YE‚š µÑ€AN5ýjˆE%˜ÃS*ã½lÝ(n#0å¥¹oe<-,X^CÒä•Sš©çj½r—’XäÊ,=ÌjëLKˆÈgžòVè4Œ¦»4K}à–g_E¢x$º%´ÖÆÑ×(GbVÂ iú“oÃå¹#Ê¶`ÊÖ·Ú³˜®Õ+AiôsÒn«¦þÝŸC®š904ŽX®ä¿æqôb Ûþu“ÔÄ˜ÍÚY‡ÐâÜ±kŸŠ†ø«0dê‘Úå:!ä“ž¡÷ž4N>¼l¸\B‰¸ þgWïc+oòä§œ%õõ¯9â}«ëØ~:_Ájƒf>4³?åüœÕ:3ƒ£J½
D}¾lÔf^ÌÒéºX€?ã.Ý§ãv‘Æ½ÞªoWg°’0~¹wƒã#
endstream
endobj

11 0 obj
<<
/BBox [ 0 0 150 22 ]
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 144
/Resources <<
/Font <<
/Helv 7 0 R
>>
>>
/Subtype /Form
/Type /XObject
>>
stream
–!¥ýÕ6;:X“‘’:ñ—˜¶¼í¬æ%4C7Æb.“K)Ì5|äªëBé´{„^±A³OÌéRùäz¡Óþ™9¼   MFfÒÀ‘1º`nŽIÙ½Hœ÷ÉýÍ =jDŒTìåÒµ¡IùŠZ¸#K®–MÕtÞòxñI['kÍTIê‰Þö™·ýMB€¼ëþ7ffk_
endstream
endobj

16 0 obj
<<
/Filter /Standard
/V 4
/Length 128
/CF <<
/StdCF <<
/AuthEvent /DocOpen
/CFM /AESV2
/Length 16
>>
>>
/StmF /StdCF
/StrF /StdCF
/R 4
/O <8a93ac1e4c390a3351364adb88835ac7c283cf5a348242ece01d07acf8ba4ec6>
/U <183a62d049153a60bbd815f01c42d5be00000000000000000000000000000000>
/P -4
>>
endobj

17 0 obj
<<
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Type /ObjStm
/N 12
/First 79
/Length 1100
>>
stream
xœ¥VÛnÛ8}÷WÌ[Ý‡˜º8–]ÛAƒn#—Ým‹>Ð-¥D—"³ñ~ýI”%´Øb/HŠœ9gfÎŒÄ„PDaÐ”¢xF3ŠSJ(Žç4§iÐ‚fxÆC‡FS bŠ¢hJa
f^b]Äôúõˆ­ŒàVêrÍ­ ñúUDÓ â`1]DÁEpù"^¼ô~ÚÐx»¾¾ø}uàe.h“Éúl1‰'ñ,„×{}G´h‰>Á¸5:s© Ç1Û_(¹£ñÁÚcõŠ±\ÚƒÛMR]°·ú˜É2gÞçåËÑ›7£:Óejôµ6jè±„å·œ.Ûý–ç¢‚$ÍæátÄV0+wë»¦äk]Úæá­POP¯À¿ìZ
•Uôjâ”¾tÈ•vÀ„#öN6æ…7û8MèÎ÷ŠW¢  Ñð+S>b›2ÕuYukšïÝÎ6Øš!ìˆjÜ¹Þm“ä
Ã.E¶^Ò8 ¼¥ÆéÃº®¥ñ
ñ‚8ebÏ²ôÄ•0]Óå‚½k¯V( h~šúØ¶-gÄîDja‹£IÌ.6‰.'I’`x(œ·§Áœ’iÒ~ò›ÌraQ    Ä³­Ç¡-jY–çÈY+M÷›¾§µi¨7ºšI~¥Ÿ}Ž3Ìp²hm¹PuÖåZigRt<u}'Îí–û½ ¦vúL˜¶3â   N)7ºÄ"MêŠ½ÏÄ2myšÖüìàÊœW(î°Ó¹.ÅWb¦n³Re‚â±oN[QáP  ZÌˆå†ƒ:Œæˆâ”€f<Ï1í~ÍvŠê—ÇJVx*2^°–íºW!°žÖï#TM %öv°52?`_ÈÒç(Œ=hWñ2óI!Ð#ØïZ|·óðf;°›0-‡5<7P`/ë,‰ýR©&ãÛ
±{/åÇLBé¦°OþŠ*QU )Ðà«¼õÏv
g±3OèOêLÝ¯v³º[ú«(wÜ`Yû©>ž|¾Úd{)d ñ“ÁtŽNa¬ˆMðoš'rY¡F
ž¶ù‰ÜdtT®òZÚ?tå ¨Ä7ÙÌý–§ß5V8¼   q#»ÔY=0-kŠ±UŠ#¡r Bv¯R§šôæóÆüÍqcë¹Àó«½å+
1îlÙÎ[ú¸Ëá°.Û1dË^’e;ŸKôduÎeãI6žd3$Ùôàïwãýn†~7½ßÆ¢‹|ð[ºõ Û!è¶sêÁ¾Kò¨N8ôóðè=Ããá±G~ôö‡ƒ6õ{!Liß)˜¸§àÞ…)¸O‚÷T¼•‰×³LÂ“O"†$¢Kï'½ŸúÉÞOÔ2•>¸ö íAzÒSÎä“lŽ¼HÎãÇ»!Þõ¸“·ÛV¤ÓÙr¾¤º+¨û<þÝ]üŸ»ºÿ?á¿à~ü?¤OÉg=¸'¸C~óâ‚*—e%¿×á_2^\i•ýÚŸÉ—¿ 74²
endstream
endobj

18 0 obj
<<
/Size 19
/Root 2 0 R
/Encrypt 16 0 R
/Info 15 0 R
/ID [ <9d483d866cf0fe86e9c325dd28c40e76> <9d483d866cf0fe86e9c325dd28c40e76> ]
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Type /XRef
/Length 63
/W [ 1 2 2 ]
/Index [ 0 3 4 15 ]
>>
stream
xœ%ÉÙ   À  ÑYsŸRBÊ°JÛêâÏƒa€R™ bÏÁŒf2³Yt~ý®f3»9teÐý7Þù7±
endstream
endobj

startxref
4923
%%EOF
```

Comment: Is this a version working for you? Then posting it as an answer is correct. Or is this a non-working next try? In that case it should be added to the question instead of being posted as an answer. I just tested the PDF with Adobe Acrobat and it doesn't even open. The reason is simple: It is a known quirk of Adobe Acrobat that it requires the document catalog object _not_ to be in an object stream but in your file it is. It looks like the pdf-lib still has a number of teething problems...

Comment: "It looks like the pdf-lib still has a number of teething problems...", yeah that what I think.
"Or is this a non-working next try? In that case it should be added to the question instead of being posted as an answer", it's because the number of characters, i couldn't added it in the question.
" I just tested the PDF with Adobe Acrobat and it doesn't even open. The reason is simple: It is a known quirk of Adobe Acrobat that it requires the document catalog object not to be in an object stream but in your file it is.", i'll see about this
My objectif is to encrypt clients pdf in client-side.